# Smallest N elements of an array with their location

Tags: matlab

I have an array called `Acc_Std` of size 1 Row and 222 Columns.

I need to have the smallest `100` values in each that array but with their original location.

I have written this code but, actually, doesn't work:

```
for Col = 1:222 

    [Std_Cont, Std_Loc]  = min(Acc_Std(:));
    Sort_Std_Cont(Col,1) = Std_Cont;
    Sort_Std_Loc(Col,1)  = Std_Loc;

    Acc_Std(Std_Loc) = []; % Here is the problem in my code
end
```

Comment: I don't understand -- what is the size of `Acc_Std`?

Comment: What doesn't work?  What are you trying to do on that line, and what is it not doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [both outputs of `sort`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html):

```
% Example data
Acc_Std = randi(10, 1,10);

% Extract the smallest N elements
N = 3;

% Sort, while saving the original indices
[B, indices] = sort(Acc_Std);

% Now extract the N smallest elements
smallest_N = B(1:N);

% Check that they are indeed located at the
% indices returned by sort()
isequal(smallest_N, Acc_Std(indices(1:N)))
```

Result of executing this little script:

```
ans =
     1
```

Comment: @ Rody Oldenhuis , I really appreciate your help! but you havent stored the location before the sort? i want the smallest 100 value from the original array with it's original location

Comment: @Neamah 100 smallest elements: `B(1:100)`. Corresponding locations: `indices(1:100)`. That is what you're asking, right?

Comment: @ Rody Oldenhuis! you are so kind, I haven't checked the variable indices.Smart people like you make our life so simple. Kind Regards.